# How to implement Exception Filter in ASP.NET Core Razor Pages

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, exception, razor-pages

I would like to rewrite my ASP.NET Core MVC application to ASP.NET Core Razor Pages.

I want to handle my custom exception, which I did in the ASP.NET Core MVC via `ExceptionFilterAttribute`:

```
public class ControllerExceptionFilterAttribute : ExceptionFilterAttribute
{
    private readonly ITempDataDictionaryFactory _tempDataDictionaryFactory;
    private readonly IModelMetadataProvider _modelMetadataProvider;

    public ControllerExceptionFilterAttribute(ITempDataDictionaryFactory tempDataDictionaryFactory,
        IModelMetadataProvider modelMetadataProvider)
    {
        _tempDataDictionaryFactory = tempDataDictionaryFactory;
        _modelMetadataProvider = modelMetadataProvider;
    }

    public override void OnException(ExceptionContext context)
    {
        if (!(context.Exception is UserFriendlyErrorPageException) &&
            !(context.Exception is UserFriendlyViewException)) return;

        ProcessException(context, tempData);
    }

    private void ProcessException(ExceptionContext context, ITempDataDictionary tempData)
    {
        if (!(context.ActionDescriptor is ControllerActionDescriptor controllerActionDescriptor)) return;

        const string errorViewName = "Error";

        var result = new ViewResult
        {
            ViewName = context.Exception is UserFriendlyViewException
                ? controllerActionDescriptor.ActionName
                : errorViewName,
            TempData = tempData,
            ViewData = new ViewDataDictionary(_modelMetadataProvider, context.ModelState)
            {
                {"Notifications", tempData[NotificationHelpers.NotificationKey]},
            }
        };

        //For UserFriendlyException is necessary return model with latest form state
        if (context.Exception is UserFriendlyViewException exception)
        {
            result.ViewData.Model = exception.Model;
        }

        context.ExceptionHandled = true;
        context.Result = result;
    }
}
```

ExceptionFilter handled that if `UserFriendlyViewException` happened the view kept same but user got nice UI toast message. In case of `UserFriendlyErrorPageException` the user was redirected to Error view and there was an error message.

How can I do this same with Razor Pages? I cannot find any `ExceptionFilterAttribute`.

Comment: Razor Page filters IPageFilter and IAsyncPageFilter allow Razor Pages to run code before and after a Razor Page handler is run.Reference official documents for the case:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/razor-pages/filter?view=aspnetcore-6.0

Comment: Did you ever found a solution? I can use the `ExceptionFilterAttribute` in net 6, but it gives a warning on a handler method (not supported there)